# Is it possible to purchase a dedicated IP without hosting?

Tags: static-ip

I require a static IP address for the sole purpose of fowarding to an existing domain. Is this possible?

Does such a service exist? I am not interested in dedicated IP addons to hosting or any hosting at all.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Depending upon your telecom or hosting scenario this is possible though some companies resist doing this at the consumer level but love these exercises at the commercial level.

I do not know your situation, however, I have purchased connectivity with a block as large as 64 IP address and as few as 8 IP addresses (or one). I have also been a webhost. For a webhost company, it may be trivial to provide an additonal IP address divorced from your server, however, because of how IP addresses are assigned, it would have to reside somewhere within the hosting company infrastructure.

If you have DSL, then this may also be trivial, though you may have to bump up your service level to commercial. Cable? Same answer. Just know that the IP address will have to be assigned and operational within the telecom infrastructure but that could be at your house or office if you have service.

It is all about routing and how IP addresses are assigned.

While I do not know your scenario, I would call your local telecom providers and explain what you are trying to do. If they were smart, they would listen carefully. Just know that when you call, you may not get the most service options knowledgeable employee so you may have to get bumped to someone who knows how to work the system from the inside.

I used to consult to all the worlds major telecoms. You can get an IP address along with some kind of service. Webhost? The same thing. If you are trying to get an IP address without service, then the answer gets trickier and the short answer is that it may not be possible.

I hope I answered your question.

Comment: looking more for a fowarding service rather than a connection. I am looking at this in the exact same way you register a domain name. I want to register an IP for the sole purpose of fowarding to another location just like a domain does. No bandwith or disk space required. Sorry if I was unclear.

Comment: Sorry. If that is a service, I am unaware of it. Then again, I am learning new *stuff* each and every day. It may be out there, but I have no ideas for you. Perhaps someone else will. Good Luck!